# Looking for Gummi for Windows

Tags: ide, gummi

So as some of you are probably aware of the original website for the Gummi LaTeX editor has gone down. Now a recent fork has arrived for Linux on [Github](https://github.com/aitjcize/Gummi) but there is no associated Windows exectutable. I was not certain where else to ask so I thought I'd try here: Are there any of you with a setup exe (the `gummi-w32-unstable-5.exe` was the latest) that you could upload somewhere so I can get it? I've tried scouring the Internet for any of the setup exe's and can't find it, going as far as to use the [WayBackMachine](http://web.archive.org/web/20131030151625/http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi/files) to try and retrieve the file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems a bit off-topic for the site, unfortunately, as it's not really about TeX and friends. Perhaps someone will be able to give you a suggestion in the comments, but I imagine the question will get closed. Once you have 20 reputation, you might try asking in the chat room, too.

Comment: @AdamLiter I thought as much but wasn't completely sure. Thank you, I'll look into using the chat room once I've met the requirements.

Comment: I've given you an upvote to help you get closer! Best of luck finding a windows version of this.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try running Linux software in Windows, this page has info:
[Five ways to run Linux software in Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/170870/5-ways-to-run-linux-software-on-windows/)

One of the solutions is called Cygwin and Gummi has been ported to this:

[Gummi on Cygwin](http://sourceforge.net/p/cygwin-ports/gummi/ci/master/tree/gummi.cygport)

I have not tried any of these as I am mainly a Linux guy.

OR

Install a Linux disto on a USB stick, install the latex distribution on the USB stick, install Gummi. Boot your computer with the USB stick to run Linux and Gummi.

Best regards, 
John

Answer (score 2):

I dug that file up. Here is the link: http://tinyurl.com/gummi-w32-unstable-5-exe

Its MD5 hash is 5e9346e6b307fbb1c6662b5ace1fb048, that matches the one shown in your link to [WayBackMachine](http://web.archive.org/web/20131030151625/http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi/files).

Answer (score 0):

I have a copy of it archived from October 2014, and I just managed to install a copy of the beta version of gummi on my new Windows machine.  If you would like to PM me your email, I can send you a temporary link for the install file.

I also contacted the creator Alexander van der Meij; he said that a Windows install file should be up on the new website sometime this week.