# Any Windows LaTeX editor with live preview feature?

Tags: editors

I have been a Linux user for a long time, but recently for some reasons I started using Windows.

While in Linux, my favorite LaTeX editor was Gummi which included among other, the feature of live preview. It means that while you write your code, you can see the preview of the page you are working with, and after any change of the code, the preview changes as well (even though with some delay), without the need to recompile your code.

Now, being in Windows, I used the Texmaker, I guess that it  must be among the most popular editors. But I found no live preview feature, instead every time I compile my document, the PDF viewer returns to the first page, which is somehow destructive when someone works with a portion of a specific page.

To make a long story short, is there a Windows Tex editor which provides live preview as Gummi does?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: see [latex-editor-for-windows-with-live-preview](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/latex-editor-for-windows-with-live-preview) and [Comparison_of_TeX_editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors)

Comment: Try www.overleaf.com (it's online).

Comment: I am not in the  dark side of the Force, but al least in Linux the dead preview of  texworks  left you in the page that you are working. Other  option could  be use some external PDF  viewer instead of the editor preview (some in Linux  as Xreader reload automatically the PDF after any change on disk without jump to the first page).

Comment: Note that most Linux solutions work on Windows too, thanks to godsends like [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/), [MobaXTerm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) et al.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preview functions are very much down to editor & some win gui users like the constant character by character approach of Bakoma or LyX, However the simplicity of gummi (on windows) compiling the file before it has even finished loading the start-up message and then compiling every one second that your not editing is impressive & I can see it is a familiarity that would be hard to match. So why not stick with what you know?

Here is a link to the last version available https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328493/170109 combine that with a portable basic TeX Live 2019, which includes a backup default GUI editor (Texworks if ever needed) and your good to go on a usb stick etc.

[image]

So quick to make changes just drop this into the preamble,

```
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\pagecolor[rgb]{0.,0.3,0.6}  
\color[rgb]{1,1,1}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do an almost instant live preview in TeXstudio  (https://www.texstudio.org/) by Options => Configure TeXstudio => Internal PDF Viewer and check the option "Auto-recompile document on changes".

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.texpad.com

It has (instant) live preview when set to compile with it's built-in LaTeX engine. The Windows version is still beta.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tex studio as idicate over [here](https://youtu.be/hO1LmNtKg1w?si=6QU-Mny6pgTTEEN_)

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is nice, but IMHO [TDH's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708488/277964) already contains the main point of this answer. So maybe adding the screenshot to that answer would be better.

Comment: Yeah I hope an admin could move my answer. Thanks !

Comment: You can add the image yourself to another answer. The community will then decide, whether the edit is acceptable. Then you can delete your own answer. I also could add edit TDH's answer to add your image, but improving answers is also honored, so if you'd do it, you get the points.